# Automated grep() across multiple columns in large dataset in R

Tags: r, regex

**EDIT** Reproducible example at the bottom...

I am working with a large dataset (pooled NHAMCS from the CDC):

`> dim(ed0509)
[1] 174020    514`

I'm having trouble using `grep()` to identify rows in a data frame based on patterns in multiple column variables `DIAG1` `DIAG2` `DIAG3` based on a vector list of interest `SSTI.list`. The condition is that if this pattern is identified in either one of column variables, then I want to pull that row number out to ultimately use this to subset the data to create a new categorical column `SSTI.cat`  in the dataset (0 or 1).

`SSTI.list <- c("035", "566", "60883", "6110", "6752", "6751", "680","681","682","683","684","684","685","686", "7048", "70583","7070", "7078", "7079", "7071", "7280", "72886", "7714", "7715", "7854", "9583", "99662", "99762", "9985")`

Since I am dealing with a pretty long list >1000s of elements, I'm trying to automate this process using a for loop. The desired output is having new variables that contain the list of rows for each value in the vector `SSTI.list`. I have mainly having issues running a for loop within `grep()` and I get the error:

`argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

What I have tried to do so far is:

`diags <- c(ed0509$DIAG1,ed0509$DIAG2,ed0509$DIAG3)`

`for (i in SSTI.list){
assign(paste("var",i,sep=""),grep(paste("^",i,"",sep=""),diags,value=F))
}`

`SSTI.comb` would be the final list of rows (all of `var`i) that identified the patterns in `SSTI.list` from the for loop that would be used to create the categorical variable `SSTI.cat`

Then used the `data.table` package to create the categorical variable.

`SSTI.comb<-sort(as.numeric(SSTI.comb))`

`setDT(ed0509)[SSTI.comb,SSTI.cat:=1][,SSTI.cat:=0]`

**EDIT** for reproducibility, sorry about that...

```
DIAG1=c("00000","4659-","0356-","5664-","771--","7715-","78791")
DIAG2=c("3829-","00000","00000","4659-","7854-","00000","566--")
DIAG3=c("9985-","00000","00000","00000","00000","00000","00000")
df<-data.frame(DIAG1,DIAG2,DIAG3)`

SSTI.list <- c("035","9985","7854","771","7715")

for (i in SSTI.list){
assign(paste("var",i,sep=""),grep(paste("^",i,"",sep=""),diags,value=F))
}
```

Conceptually I would like to have an output where the new column variable attached to `df` would indicate that the 1st, 3rd, 5th and 6th rows are identified to satisfy the pattern indicated in `SSTI.list`

```
DIAG1 DIAG2 DIAG3 SSTI.cat
1 00000 3829- 9985-        1
2 4659- 00000 00000        0
3 0356- 00000 00000        1
4 5664- 4659- 00000        0
5 771-- 7854- 00000        1
6 7715- 00000 00000        1
7 78791 566-- 00000        0
```

Comment: Can you make the question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding an example of your data set and of your expected output dataset?

Comment: Do you need an element in `SSTI.list` to match exactly with an element in the data, or does it only have match part of the value. For example, if an element in the data is `"683035"` should that result in a match with `"035"` from `SSTI.list`, or should only "035" in the data match "035" in `SSTI.list`?

Comment: @thepule I added a reproducible example and the desired output.
@eipi10 I had used the `^` in `grep()` to indicate that I want the element based from the beginning of the string, so `"035"` from `SSTI.list` would identify `"0351-"` or `"03568"` but not `"683035"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with fake data that I cooked up before you added your data. Let me know if this is what you had in mind:

```
SSTI.list <- c("035", "566", "60883", "6110", "6752", "6751", "680","681","682","683","684","684",
               "685","686", "7048", "70583","7070", "7078", "7079", "7071", "7280", "72886", 
               "7714", "7715", "7854", "9583", "99662", "99762", "9985")

# Fake data
set.seed(10)
dat = as.data.frame(replicate(5, sample(c(SSTI.list, 1e5:(1e5+1000)),10)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

> ```
>        V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
> 1  100493 100642 100861 100522 100254
> 2  100286 100555 100604 100066 100206
> 3  100409 100087 100767 100145   7048
> 4  100682 100583 100336 100895 100719
> 5  100058 100338 100387 100404 100227
> 6  100202 100410 100695 100737 100136
> 7  100252 100024 100829 100813   7078
> 8  100249 100241 100216 100947 100468
> 9  100600 100378 100758 100671 100076
> 10 100998 100824 100334 100482 100789
> ```

```
# Match any instance of a pattern within any element of the data
dat[apply(dat, 1, function(i) any(grepl(paste(SSTI.list, collapse="|"), i))),]
```

> ```
>       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
> 3 100409 100087 100767 100145   7048
> 4 100682 100583 100336 100895 100719  # "100682 matches "682" in SSTI.list
> 7 100252 100024 100829 100813   7078
> ```

```
# Match only if a data element is exactly the same as one of the patterns.
dat[apply(dat, 1, function(i) any(grepl(paste(paste0("^",SSTI.list,"$"), collapse="|"), i))),]
```

> ```
>       V1     V2     V3     V4   V5
> 3 100409 100087 100767 100145 7048
> 7 100252 100024 100829 100813 7078
> ```

If you just want the row indices of matching rows:

```
which(apply(dat, 1, function(i) any(grepl(paste(SSTI.list, collapse="|"), i))))

[1] 3 4 7
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I had wanted! I'm new to programming in R and I really appreciate your help with this. I was wondering if this is the only way to do this or if there are any existing packages that would do the equivalent?

Comment: There are almost always multiple ways to do things in R, and I'd be surprised if my answer is the most efficient. It's possible the `stringr`, `stringi`, or `data.table` packages have something simpler and/or faster, and there might be a better way in base R as well. Hopefully, someone will come along with other options.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into those packages. I have another question, can `dat` in `apply()` be replaced with a vector that identifies specific columns in `dat`, in other words if I had only wanted to only consider `DIAG1` and `DIAG3`? or just `DIAG2`?

Comment: Then do `dat[ , c("DIAG1", "DIAG3", "DIAG5")]`. Or, more succinctly, `dat[ , paste0("DIAG", c(1,3,5)]`. Or, `dat[ , grep("1|3|5", names(dat))]` (note, the latter will also match "DIAG11" or "DIAG35", so you have to be careful about your pattern). Like I said, many ways to do things in R!